# Django forcing UTF-8 on misconfigured MySQL Server

Tags: django, utf-8, mysql-python

I am using the MySQL-Python driver v1.2.5 with Python 2.7.x and Django 1.5.x.

I have a situation where I require a Django application to work entirely in UTF-8, yet the production MySQL server is left configured in Latin1 and, apparently, I have no option to alter the configuration of the DB server, so, I've investigated options that I can control -- the MySQLDB connection configuration. I've arrived at the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mysql_db',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'CHARSET': 'utf8mb4',
        'USE_UNICODE': True,  # Already implied by above though
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB; SET NAMES utf8mb4;',
        }
    }
}
```

Is this sufficient to allow my code to operate (w.r.t. DB I/O) entirely in UTF-8? Are there any potential gotchas I should watch out for?

Comment: You mean apart from https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4?

Comment: Ooh, interesting stuff! Thanks @Boldewyn. Will update the above accordingly and see if anyone else has anything to add.